# Convert rows to column from javascript array

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am working on ReactJS and was wondering if there is a way to convert a javascript array from row into column.

```
[
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2005', question: 'Standing upright', answer: 'Moderate' },
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2006', question: 'Standing upright', answer: 'Severe' },
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2007', question: 'Standing upright', answer: 'Extreme' },
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2008', question: 'Standing upright', answer: 'Severe' },
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2005', question: 'Going up or down stairs', answer: 'Extreme' },
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2006', question: 'Going up or down stairs', answer: 'Moderate' },
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2007', question: 'Going up or down stairs', answer: 'Extreme' },
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2008', question: 'Going up or down stairs', answer: 'Moderate' }
]
```

I want to convert this into data an html table/div like this:

```
Study: Koos
Question                | 05/06/2005 | 05/06/2006 | 05/06/2007 | 05/06/2008 
Standing upright        | Moderate   | Severe     | Extreme    | Severe
Going up or down stairs | Extreme    | Moderate   | Extreme    | Moderate
```

I found this excellent library - [json-to-pivot-json](https://github.com/itsmejainh/json-to-pivot-json). This is something that I wanted to use, but only issue is that aggregates the value.

I see lot of examples in sql but couldn't find anything similar for javascript.

To help others, I am adding the complete JSX code to display the result as suggested by `Rafael`.

```
var output = coll2tbl(surveyResult, "question", "date", "answer"); 

const mappedCells = output.cells.map((row, index) => {
    row.unshift(output.row_headers[index]);
    return row;
})

<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Question</th>
        {
            output.col_headers.map(c => {
                return (
                    <th>{c}</th>
                );
            })                                    
        }   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {
        mappedCells.map(row => (
            <tr>{ row.map(cell => (<td>{cell}</td>))}</tr>
        ))
    }                   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if you need to aggregate  the existing array of  object then build a new object  out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Collection to Table-Ready Data-Structure

Pass the collection and the appropriate property descriptors to the `coll2tbl` function and it will output a table-ready data-structure:

```
var data = [
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2005', question: 'Standing upright', answer: 'Moderate' },
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2006', question: 'Standing upright', answer: 'Severe' },
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2007', question: 'Standing upright', answer: 'Extreme' },
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2008', question: 'Standing upright', answer: 'Severe' },
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2005', question: 'Going up or down stairs', answer: 'Extreme' },
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2006', question: 'Going up or down stairs', answer: 'Moderate' },
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2007', question: 'Going up or down stairs', answer: 'Extreme' },
    { study: 'KOOS', date: '05/06/2008', question: 'Going up or down stairs', answer: 'Moderate' }
];

function get_prop(obj, prop) {
    return prop.split('.').reduce((o,k) => obj[k], obj);
}

function coll2tbl(coll, row_header, col_header, cell) {
    var table = {};
    var row_headers = [];
    var cols = {};

    coll.forEach(a => {
        var h = get_prop(a, row_header);
        if (h in table === false) {
            table[h] = {};
            row_headers.push(h);
        }
        var c = get_prop(a, col_header);
        cols[c] = null;
        table[h][c] = get_prop(a, cell);
    });

    var cells = [];
    for (var row in table)
        cells.push(Object.values(table[row]));

    return { row_headers, col_headers: Object.keys(cols), cells };
}

var table = coll2tbl(data, 'question', 'date', 'answer');
console.log(table);
```

Output:

```
{ row_headers: [ 'Standing upright', 'Going up or down stairs' ],
  col_headers: [ '05/06/2005', '05/06/2006', '05/06/2007', '05/06/2008' ],
  cells: 
   [ [ 'Moderate', 'Severe', 'Extreme', 'Severe' ],
     [ 'Extreme', 'Moderate', 'Extreme', 'Moderate' ] ] }
```

### Making the thead

1. add a static `th` to the beginning of the `thead`, this is where your `Question` string will go.
2. add a `th` per *ch* in col_headers

### Making the tbody

1. iterate the `cells` returned by `coll2tbl()`.

   1. every parent iteration, make a new `tr`.
   2. add the row header cell by using the parent iterator's counter to grab the corresponding row header (`table.row_headers[i]`).
   3. The inner loop will create the cells, `td`, (`table.cells[i][j]`).

Ideally, you would make a react component that takes this data-structure and creates the html for you.

Comment: I have posted a question for a bug in your solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197974/convert-json-data-to-table