# Calculating while converting (array of objects) columns to row data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following array:

```
var test =[
{Date:"2020-06-01", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"A",line:100,acc:1000,tom:10000},
{Date:"2020-06-01", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"B",line:200,acc:2000,tom:20000},
{Date:"2020-06-01", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"C",line:300,acc:3000,tom:30000},
{Date:"2020-06-02", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"A",line:400,acc:4000,tom:40000},
{Date:"2020-06-02", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"B",line:500,acc:5000,tom:50000},
{Date:"2020-06-02", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"C",line:600,acc:6000,tom:60000}
]
```

What i'm trying to achieve is this result:

```
var result=[
{Date:"2020-06-01", Type:"ZT", QltA:100, QltB:200, QltC:300, totalQlt:600, totalAcc:6000, totalTom:60000}, 
{Date:"2020-06-02", Type:"ZT", QltA:400, QltB:500, QltC:600, totalQlt:1500, totalAcc:15000, totalTom:150000},
]
```

1. Date must be unique,
2. Qlt's value is always (A or B or C) so it is converted as key name QltA, QltB and QltC
3. All the other (line, acc and tom) are the sum of corresponding Qlts.

i've tried the reverse approach of this post [Convert rows to column from javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699919/convert-rows-to-column-from-javascript-array)
 but i didn't managed to get it work, moreover i had troubles of calculating the sum.

I know that it is something tricky here, it will be great if you could provide a solution and a sort explanation in order to understand the logic?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please post what you have tried and where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  { Date:"2020-06-01", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"A", line:100, acc:1000, tom:10000 },
  { Date:"2020-06-01", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"B", line:200, acc:2000, tom:20000 },
  { Date:"2020-06-01", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"C", line:300, acc:3000, tom:30000 },
  { Date:"2020-06-02", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"A", line:400, acc:4000, tom:40000 },
  { Date:"2020-06-02", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"B", line:500, acc:5000, tom:50000 },
  { Date:"2020-06-02", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"C", line:600, acc:6000, tom:60000 }
];

const result = [...
  // iterate over the list while updating a Map of Date-Items
  data.reduce((map, { Date, Type, Qlt, line, acc, tom }) => {
    // get value of Date from map if exists
    const prev = map.get(Date) || {};
    // set/update map values
    map.set(
      Date,
      { 
        ...prev,
        Date,
        Type,
        [`Qlt${Qlt}`]: (prev.line || 0 ) + line,
        totalQlt: (prev.totalQlt || 0) + line,
        totalAcc: (prev.totalAcc || 0) + acc,
        totalTom: (prev.totalTom || 0) + tom
      }
    );
    return map;
  }, new Map)
  // return updated items of same dates
  .values()
];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: interesting approach with map.set(), by updating on every iteration, thank you!

Comment: do you have any ideas/approach on the above update?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a `group by` operation by the `Date` property. Here implemented with [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

You can replace the [nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) with an OR short circuit if you need.

```
a[Date] ??= { Date, Type, ...};
// or
a[Date] || (a[Date] = { Date, Type, ...});
```

```js
const
  input = [{ Date: "2020-06-01", Type: "ZT", Qlt: "A", line: 100, acc: 1000, tom: 10000 }, { Date: "2020-06-01", Type: "ZT", Qlt: "B", line: 200, acc: 2000, tom: 20000 }, { Date: "2020-06-01", Type: "ZT", Qlt: "C", line: 300, acc: 3000, tom: 30000 }, { Date: "2020-06-02", Type: "ZT", Qlt: "A", line: 400, acc: 4000, tom: 40000 }, { Date: "2020-06-02", Type: "ZT", Qlt: "B", line: 500, acc: 5000, tom: 50000 }, { Date: "2020-06-02", Type: "ZT", Qlt: "C", line: 600, acc: 6000, tom: 60000 }],

  result = Object
    .values(input
      .reduce((a, { Date, Type, Qlt, line, acc, tom }) => {
        a[Date] ??= { Date, Type, totalQlt: 0, totalAcc: 0, totalTom: 0 };
        
        a[Date][`Qlt${Qlt}`] = line;
        a[Date].totalQlt += line;
        a[Date].totalAcc += acc;
        a[Date].totalTom += tom;
        return a;
      }, {})
    );

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create set of dates
2. Add for each date(element in the set) an object
3. Fill the object with values from the input using for loop

```js
var test =[
  {date:"2020-06-01", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"A",line:100,acc:1000,tom:10000},
  {date:"2020-06-01", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"B",line:200,acc:2000,tom:20000},
  {date:"2020-06-01", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"C",line:300,acc:3000,tom:30000},
  {date:"2020-06-02", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"A",line:400,acc:4000,tom:40000},
  {date:"2020-06-02", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"B",line:500,acc:5000,tom:50000},
  {date:"2020-06-02", Type:"ZT", Qlt:"C",line:600,acc:6000,tom:60000}
]
  
 function resOBj(date,Type,QltA,QltB,QltC,totalQlt,totalAcc,totalTom){
  this.date=date, 
  this.Type=Type,
  this.QltA=QltA, 
  this.QltB=QltB, 
  this.QltC=QltC, 
  this.totalQlt=totalQlt, 
  this.totalAcc=totalAcc, 
  this.totalTom=totalTom
}


convertData=(test)=>{
  if (test===undefined){
    return test
  }
  let result=[]
  let setDates= new Set()
  test.forEach(t => {
    setDates.add(t.date)
  })

  for(const value of setDates){
    result.push(new resOBj(value,"",0,0,0,0,0,0))  
    for (let i=0;i<test.length;i++){
      if (test[i].date===value){
        result[result.length-1].Type = test[i].Type
        result[result.length-1].QltA = test[i].Qlt==="A"?test[i].line:result[result.length-1].QltA
        result[result.length-1].QltB = test[i].Qlt==="B"?test[i].line:result[result.length-1].QltB
        result[result.length-1].QltC = test[i].Qlt==="C"?test[i].line:result[result.length-1].QltC
        result[result.length-1].totalQlt += test[i].line
        result[result.length-1].totalAcc += test[i].acc
        result[result.length-1].totalTom += test[i].tom
      }
     }
  } 
  return result
}

console.log(convertData(test))
```